# Ошибка E2029 В Delphi

Tags: delphi

```
procedure eraseSubstr(const pos:vector; var text:string; const pattern:string);
var
  len, iter, end_, endPos:Integer;
  t:string;
begin
  t:=text;

  len:=Length(pattern);
  if (Length(pos) < 2) then
  begin
    Delete(t, pos[0], length);
  end;

end;
```

Ошибка возникает на функции `Delete`.

Ошибка - `[dcc32 Error] Functions.pas(58): E2029 '(' expected but ')' found`
Может, кто-то с подобным сталкивался? Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Delete(t, pos[0], len);
```

Ты пишешь `Length` - это функция `System.Length` естественно он ожидает открывающую `(` с параметрами, а ты ему суёшь `)`

Причём Length это функция ядра компилятора она имеет особое свойство.

Comment: что за функция ядра компилятора и особые свойства?